# Organising asp.net website development process

Tags: asp.net, web

Is there a standard practice to organize the process of developing a simple website. there is no use implementing MVC as there is no data base involved. It will be very useful in organizing the project and separating

- the aspx files and master
- page content(this can be very useful in implementing simple cms techniques)
- user controls
- scripts
- styles
- images

is there any industry standard or best practice for this.?

thanks in advance :)

**Update:** yes the way i have listed is convenient. but it would be great if i could separate server codes and files like master,aspx.. and the actual page content.

**One more reason for not using MVC:** I usually outsource the SEO process. Now an MVC application can be greek/latin for my SEO expert. :)

**The final structure:**
Project

1. Images
2. Scripts
3. Styles
4. Images
5. Weblets
6. Pagelets
7. aspx files..

the images, styles and scripts will contain only those that are common for the whole project. The weblets and pagelets are in the idea as follows...
**Weblets** should contain a collection of weblets. A weblet is folder containing a user control,it's styles,scripts,images etc.,
**Pagelets** should contain a collection of pagelets. A pagelet is a folder containing the content for the aspx page. If there is an aspx file named "aboutUs.aspx" then there is a corresponding pagelet named "aboutUs" which contains aboutUs.html,it's styles,scripts and images. the aspx page should only include them here.This can be very useful in configuring CMS.
If there can be betterments please do post..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is right there is no such industry standard for this. But in my opinion i really like the Web Application Template from ASP.Net 4.0. It is more like MVC Template but it remain very useful in terms of scalability.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/08/26/starter-project-templates-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

Comment: this looks very interesting and useful. but the biggest problem- finding a server with .net4.0...

Comment: Ya but its not necessary to use .net 4.0 in order to follow the template they use. I personally created the similar project structure for my .net3.5 project.

Comment: have decided to create a template close to this

Answer (score 2):

No industry standards as such, but most developers I know would separate things out the way you did.

i.e. - different types of content in different directories.

Comment: I agree.  The layout mentioned by the OP is actually fairly close to what I've seen in a number of places.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.Net MVC isn't just for database applications. In fact I would suggest it's easier to work with than webforms after the small learning curve. The concept of convention over configuration will help you with your question. There is a standard structure that MVC sets up for you that works great and anybody that opens your MVC code will be able to understand where everything is.